# Directory-picker for form input using Java servlets or JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets, spring-mvc

I'd like to create a directory-picker form input element, which would allow users to select a network directory to be selected and passed as the target for a server process.  The idea is that users would browse a network share, visible to the user's machine and web server, and select a folder they would like to request to be processed by a server application.  I'd like this to function like a `<input type="file">` tag would, only allowing folder selection *instead of* files.

I have read that the HTML file-picker input does not support this behavior, but that it might be possible using Java servlets or JavaScript, though I have found no code that demonstrates this.  Is it possible to create a form element like this?  I am using Spring MVC 3, and this is an intranet application, so security is not an issue.  I am new to Java-based web development, so I don't really know where to start here.

Comment: You want them to be able to view the directory structure of the server?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: The idea is that they would select a network directory, visible to the server, that contains a set of files to be processed, in order to request the processing.

Comment: You are the server. Select a root `File`, eg. `/var/path/`, then get all sub folders/files. Then do `File#listFiles()` and populate an html `<select>` element.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Interesting idea, but that's not really what I am looking for.  I want users to be able to browse the directory structure and see what files are contained within what folders (such as the `<input type="file">` tag).  The directory structure is pretty big, a select list would be unwieldy.

Comment: An HTTP request is a one time thing, you get data and that's it, so you wouldn't be able to do it like an OS file chooser. However, you can kind of give the same impression with javascript, making separate requests for each subpath to follow.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: In this case it would function like an OS file chooser, since the directories being browsed are intranet file shares accessible on the user's Windows machine.  A JavaScript solution to this problem would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a interface for users to move in and out of directories

The servlet or Spring-MVC controller part of this is pretty simple (excluding exceptions and the such).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/network/*")
@ResponseBody  // serialize to json since you are using javascript 
public List<String> getDirectory(@RequestParam("direction") String direction, HttpServletRequest request) {
    List<String> paths = new LinkedList<String>();

    String path = request.getRequestURI();
    path = path.substring(path.indexOf("/network") + 8); // gets everything after /network

    if ("up".equals(direction)) { // want to go up one folder
        File parent = new File(path).getParentFile(); // get the parent, this might return null so have to check
        paths.addAll(Arrays.asList(parent.list()));
    } else if ("into".equals(direction)) {
        File directory = new File(path); // get all the files in the current directory
        paths.addAll(Arrays.asList(directory.list()));
    }

    return paths;
}
```

You would then make ajax requests to

```
http://www.your-intranet.com/network/var/this/path/wanted?direction=into
```

to retrieve a JSON list of all the files and folders inside it. Or

```
http://www.your-intranet.com/network/var/this/path/wanted?direction=up
```

equivalent to

```
http://www.your-intranet.com/network/var/this/path?direction=into
```

depending on where you want to do the path extraction logic (probably on the server since it knows if it is right or not).

The UI part of this is a little harder and I won't get into it, but you will have to parse the json and decide if you want to show a folder icon or some file icon with different buttons for different operations.

You would also have to play around with the paths depending on Linux or Windows OS.